# How to get user input and apped to the URL in PHP?

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I want to create a simple PHP website were user should enter any string in text box and click submit then that string should be placed in the URL

**For example:**

If user entered ***"Java"*** as their input then after clicking submit, the `URL` should change to:

```
example.com/Java
```

How it's possible any example or a sample program if possible

Comment: It's tough..!! Please show your code you have tried..!! ;)

Comment: In javacript when the button is clicked: `location.href = '/' + document.getElementById('the_id_of_the_input').value;`

Comment: I assume that the user will be redirected to that `url`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, taking your question literally, this should work

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $userInput = $_POST['userInput'];
        header('Location:example.com/'.$userInput);
    }
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="userInput"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Of course, depending on your codes, this might be used to tamper or do something bad to your codes.

Comment: Also do you have any idea how this website is made

am eager to learn that but am new to PHP

http://rubi.me/

Thanks in advance